# How to create a tab stop with a dotted leader (........)

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to create a on a word document a tab stop with dotted (.....) leader.

I'm using:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

and these objects;

```
Word.Application objWord = new Word.Application();
Word.Document objDoc; //already initialized
```

The result should be:

.............kg

.............time

.............whatever

Tab stops should be fixed at a specific length (i.e. 5cm).

How can I do it? Ms documentation is not very clear and I have not found any example.

Any advise on any documentation/tutorial that clearly explains the main concepts are welcome.

I've tried this:

```
    objWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add(3, Word.WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdLeft,Word.WdTabLeader.wdTabLeaderDots);
    objWord.Selection.TypeText("\n");
    objWord.Selection.TypeText("before");
    objWord.Selection.TypeText("\t");
    objWord.Selection.TypeText("after");
```

The result is this:

```
before  after
```

I was expecting

```
before..............after
```

Comment: Come on, what was the downvote for??

Comment: I'll try using OpenXml, at least there is more documentation.

Comment: If the code I supplied does not work for you. Then you should show what you tried. As your code above places a tab stop 0.04'' inches from the left side. What character can be printed in a width of 0.04"?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure your code is correct. I am guessing your tab(s) are getting set properly, its just that they are not spread far enough apart to be seen. On the line:

```
objWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add(3, Word.WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdLeft,Word.WdTabLeader.wdTabLeaderDots);
```

Translates into a tab stop that is 0.04” from the left... this will be too small to see. Below I converted the points to inches and set tabs at 1”, 2” and 3.5”. Hope this helps.

```
  objWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add(objWord.InchesToPoints(1), Word.WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdLeft, Word.WdTabLeader.wdTabLeaderDots);
  objWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add(objWord.InchesToPoints(2), Word.WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdLeft, Word.WdTabLeader.wdTabLeaderDots);
  objWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add(objWord.InchesToPoints(3.5f), Word.WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdLeft, Word.WdTabLeader.wdTabLeaderDots);
  objWord.Selection.TypeText("\t");
  objWord.Selection.TypeText("before");
  objWord.Selection.TypeText("\t");
  objWord.Selection.TypeText("after");
  objWord.Selection.TypeText("\t");
  objWord.Selection.TypeText("after2");
  objWord.Selection.TypeText("\t");
  objWord.Selection.TypeText("after3");
```

**Update to show where the tab at 3 points is located**

Let me see if I can explain this better. In publishing, fonts are measured using a system called “Points.” There are 72 “points” in an inch. This “point” system is the same system Word uses when placing tabs across a page. So looking at the line below:

```
objWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add(3, Word.WdAlignmentTabAlignment.wdLeft,Word.WdTabLeader.wdTabLeaderDots);
```

NOTE THE “3”… The line above will set the first tab stop 3 “points” from the left margin. In inches this translates to 3/72 = 0.0416666… of an inch. Below is a picture of where this tab stop is located.

[image]

As you can see from the red vertical line I drew down to the text that no characters can fit in such a small width therefore there is not enough room to put any tabs leaders.

I am confident that no matter what library you use to access the word document; the results will be the same!

Solution… move the tab over enough to see the leaders this is basic publishing 101.

Comment: I've tried but it did not work, same results as before.

Comment: Can you show what you tried. I tested the code above and it works as expected.